# How can I save the state of a virtual machine in GNOME Boxes?

Tags: gnome, virtualization, qemu, gnome-boxes

I used to use `virt-manager` with QEMU, however now I've started using `gnome-boxes` due to some issues with the other one. A feature however which `gnome-boxes` appears to lack is one to allow you like the other program and most ones of this kind, to save the state of the machine so that one may resume the session later on. Almost like hibernation. This is a common feature, but I am unable to find it in `gnome-boxes`, so is there something I'm missing or is this feature just lacking at this time in `gnome-boxes` 3.22?

Or is there perhaps some other way of doing this other than through `gnome-boxes`, but while still using it?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 with GNOME 3.22.

Comment: Yes! https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-boxes/stable/snapshot-create.html.en

Comment: @NickWeinberg: Please post that as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Boxes and right-click the stopped virtual machine, then select and click Properties.

[image]

If you want to do it while the machine is running, select and click Properties on the top right.

[image]

Open the Snapshots tab and click on the <kbd>+</kbd> sign to create a new snapshot of the machine.

[image]

By the way, I recommend to create new snapshots when the virtual machine is not running.